# I just want to know whats wrong in this java script code?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return ("The result is a tie!");
    } else if (choice1 = "Rock") {
        if (choice2 = "Scissorsr") {
            return "rock Wins!";
        } else if (choice2 = "Paper") {
            return "paper Wins!";
        }
    } else if (choice1 = "paper") {
        if (choice2 = "Rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else if (choice2 = "Scissors") {
            return "scissors wins!";
        }
    }
};
```

I was learning java script in codecademy and after submitting the code it gets me the error saying

> Your compare function doesn't return the correct string when comparing paper to rock.

Comment: choice == "Rock"    choice == "Paper"

Comment: Also, you misspelled `"Scissors"` in `if (choice2 = "Scissorsr") {`. I also think you want to capitalize `"Paper"` in `} else if (choice1 = "paper") {`. Just do some proofreading.

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: I think we need a reference question for this, this comes up far too often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`choice1="paper"` is an *assignment*, not a comparison. Use `===` for comparisons (unless you need type coercion, in which case use `==`)

Comment: as i am a begginer, whats the actual difference between == and === (though i now know === is for comparisions)

Comment: @Pavan: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/218196

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
var compare = function(choice1,choice2) {
   if (choice1===choice2) {
        return("The result is a tie!");
   }
   else if (choice1 == "Rock") {
       if (choice2 == "Scissors") {
            return "rock Wins!";}
       else if(choice2 == "Paper") {
            return "paper Wins!";
       }
   }

   else if (choice1 == "paper") {
       if (choice2 == "Rock") {
            return "paper wins";}
       else if (choice2 == "Scissors") {
            return "scissors wins!";
       }
   }
};
```

Comment: ok so now i get the answer! :/ as i am a beginner, whats the actual difference between == and ===